is it true that the complexity of the function is O((log(log(n))^2)?
int func2(int arr[], int n) {
    int i = 0, j, counter = 0;

    MergeSort(arr, n / 6); // 1

    while (i < n / 6) // 2
    {
        for (j = 6; j < n / 6; j *= j) // 3
            counter++;

        i = j * 6;
    }

    return counter;
}

the complexities i tried to calculate:
the complexity  for mergeSort is O(n/6log(n/6)
the complexity for while loop is O(log(log(n/6))
the complexity for inner for loop is O(log(log(n/6))
the expression i got is : O(n/6log(n/6)+O(log(log(n/6))*O(log(log(n/6))
but I'm wondering if I am right

No; the merge sort itself is O(n lg n) (the /6 is irrelevant, as a constant factor), which provides a lower bound on the complexity of func2.

I.e., it's O(n lg n) + O(while loop), so unless the while loop itself is asymoptically slower than O(n lg n), the entire function is O(n lg n) itself.

I’m voting to close this question because it’s better suited for the computer science exchange.

@Daniel Walker That's not a valid reason even if true.

It's O( n * log( n ) ).

We are usually expected to simplify, so the merge sort is O( n * log( n ) ) and the inner loop is O( log( log( n ) ) ) because we don't care about constant factors.
Ignoring overflows, i will be at least n / 6 at the start of the second pass, so the while loop will execute at most once. Its total complexity is the same as its body's.
Combining the two together, we get a complexity is O( n * log( n ) + log( log( n ) ) ).
But n * log( n ) dominates log( log( n ) ). This refers to the fact that O( n * log( n ) ) eclipses O( log( log( n ) ) ) since O( n * log( n ) + log( log( n ) ) ) is O( k * n * log( n ) ) and is thus O( n * log( n ) ).
Our final answer is therefore O( n * log( n ) ).

When I was taught this stuff back in the 1970s, they used the word "dominates" rather than "eclipses".  (More precisely ... "dominates as n tends to infinity" ... which is itself very informal.)

@Stephen C, Fine, I've adjusted the answer to also teach the formal term, but it seems really clunky now.
